# Querying AWS DynamoDB using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have inherited a DynamoDB table with three columns of which one is a key

```
 Id - String - hashKey
 ProductID - String
 UsageCount - number
```

I want to run a query/scan that logically equates to the following

```
 select ProductID, UsageCount where ProductID='abcd'
```

Although ProductID is not a key of any sort, I can use the AmazonDynamoDB console and add a filter

[image: console filter]

and get just what I want. So I assume I should be able to do the same thing with code (although everyone talks about using hash and range keys for such purposes)

I am trying to do the same thing with RUBY but not getting results...

```
 resp = $dynamodb.scan(
       :table_name => PRODUCTTABLE,
       :projection_expression => "Id, TenantId, SeatCount",
          :filter_expression => 'TenantId = abcd'
                       )
```

Could someone help me with the correct syntax for doing this? I tried numerous variations that all throw exceptions except for the above syntax that does not throw an exception but returns zero rows. So Im thinking it must be close :) (or maybe not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use both filter_expression but make it `'TenantId = :val'`

and then pass `:val` with `expression_attribute_names` and `expression_attribute_values`

Even though it's in Java, [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html) will help clear things out for you

Comment: thx! - the following syntax worked...

`resp = $dynamodb.scan(
      :table_name => "MyTable",
      :limit => 2,
      :projection_expression => "Id, DataSource, TenantId",
      :filter_expression => 'TenantId = :val',
      :expression_attribute_values => { ":val" => '6e874f58-ac9a-44ae-9ed4-9ed2e8828800' } )`